# How classify numeric values inputs in categories?

Tags: javascript, range, classification

I want to create an optimized way to classify a value in certain labels.

Example

Input: 12.2, 61, 77.7
Output: "bad", "poor", "good"

I create a simple if, but maybe exist a better way

```
let output = null;
if (rating <= 60){ output = 'bad'}
if (rating > 60){ output = 'poor'}
if (rating > 70){ output = 'good'}
if (rating > 90){ output = 'excellent'}
```

Comment: read up on fuzzy logic.. there were concepts that were helping with this

Comment: @Swift How does fuzzy logic help this?

Comment: well, if you need a unified way to define fuzzy sets, there is thing called membership function. Though in your case it looks like you want strict  borders between "quality" levels.

Comment: too complex solution for a simple problem. But thanks. I found this searching about this subject. https://github.com/sebs/es6-fuzz

Comment: If you have some requests about that library, I am happy to take Ideas for future developments of es6-fuzz

Answer (score 2):

You could use [`Array#some`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some) and iterate through an array of objects for the rating. The advantage is a good maintainable object.

> ```
> ratings = [
>     { value: 60, label: 'bad' },
>     { value: 70, label: 'poor' },
>     { value: 90, label: 'good' },
>     { value: Infinity, label: 'excellent' }
> ]
> ```

```js
function rating(v) {
    var ratings = [{ value: 60, label: 'bad' }, { value: 70, label: 'poor' }, { value: 90, label: 'good' }, { value: Infinity, label: 'excellent' }],
        label;

    ratings.some(function (a) {
        if (v <= a.value) {
            label = a.label;
            return true;
        }
    });
    return label;
}

console.log([12.2, 61, 77.7].map(rating));
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

ES6 with [`Array#find`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find)

```js
var ratings = [{ value: 60, label: 'bad' }, { value: 70, label: 'poor' }, { value: 90, label: 'good' }, { value: Infinity, label: 'excellent' }],
    rating = v => ratings.find(a => v <= a.value).label;

console.log([12.2, 61, 77.7].map(rating));
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Answer (score 1):

One better way is to creatively use `switch`:

```js
var output = null;
var rating = parseInt(prompt("Rating?"));
switch (true) {
  case (rating <= 60):
    output = 'bad';
    break;
  case (rating > 90):
    output = 'excellent';
    break;
  case (rating > 70):
    output = 'good';
    break;
  case (rating > 60):
    output = 'poor';
    break;
}
console.log(output);
```

Here, the correct organisation of the lines are very important.

Answer (score -1):

One fast way of doing this if you are fine your memory.

```js
var limits = [60,70,90,100],
     rates = ["bad","poor","good","excellent"],
    grades = limits.reduce((g,c,i,a) => i ? g.concat(Array(c-a[i-1]).fill(rates[i]))
                                          : g.concat(Array(c).fill(rates[0])),[]),
     notes = [12.2, 61, 77.7, 89.5];
notes.forEach(n => console.log(grades[Math.round(n)]));
```